# z-index property not work

Tags: jquery, css

Hi man I have following codes, and I wont to that when I'll click some button `fadeTo` only content without `#some` tag
In this case `fadeTo` involve `#some` tag

```
<div id="content">
<div id="some"></div>
</div>


#content{
width:100%;
height:100%;
outline:1px solid red;
margin:auto;
z-index:0;}


#registration,#login{
    width:350px;
    height:300px;
    outline:1px solid blue;
    display:none;
    z-index:500;
    position:fixed;}


   $(".button").click(function(){ 
            $("#some").fadeToggle();
            $("#content").fadeTo(500,0.5);
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2 div like this `<div class="a">` , `<div class="b">`
and both have a `absolute` position you can write `z-index` property

```
.a {
  z-index:1;
}
.b {
  z-index:2;
}
```

`.a` div is over `.b` div

Answer (score 4):

[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property only works on *non-static* positioned elements. i.e. you need to use one of `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed` positions for the element.

In this case, you probably need `position: relative;` CSS declaration.

---

Honestly, I'm not sure about why you are using `z-index` in this case.

If you're going to exclude the `#some` element from being treated by `.fadeTo()` method, you could wrap the content of the `#content` by an element (or elements) and apply that method to them, as follows:

```javascript
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("#content").find(':not(#some)').fadeTo(500,0.5);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="some"></div>

    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    <a href="">A link here</a> <br>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="may be an image here">
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vucujeza/1/edit)**.

Comment: Well, non-static positioned elements

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong, but im fairly certain that BOTH elements you want to include in the z-index must have non-static positioning.

So if you made your #content **and** #registration,#login non-static elements, it should work.

Comment: In fact, they just have to be in the same stacking context. When you set a `position` and `z-index` attribute to an element, it creates a new stacking context for it. Then, It acts like any other elements. You don't need to repeat the z-index on its children

Answer (score 2):

In fact, they just have to be in the same stacking context. When you set a `position` and `z-index` attribute to an element, it creates a new stacking context for it. Then, It acts like any other elements. You don't need to repeat the `z-index` on its children

As you can see in this example, the child of the second div `<div id="div2-2">` has the highest z-index `z-index:4;` But ! It is still "under" `div3` because `div3` has it own stacking context that is on top of `div2` stacking context.

http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/r7nyL/

This mean that `z-index` are completly useless inside handly created stacking contexts.