# Z-Index not working?

Tags: html, css

Please have a look at my code, I've spent several hours finding a solution to no avail. I'm not a professional Web Developer, I'm just doing this for our project at school.

http://cssdesk.com/6L2sN

What I'm trying to do is, the Black div is at the most top, and then the red below it, then green below it, same goes to the blue one. But it's doing the opposite. I don't understand why, is z-index not working as it should?

Comment: I don't see the problem, in your example the order is the one you are describing

Comment: Why using <br>? Divs are block elements. And use positive z-index.

Comment: I noticed you didn't add `px` to your `width`, `height` and `margin` attributes.

Comment: The z-index is ok for me. Why are you saying that "is not working as it should"?

Comment: I'm sorry, english is not my first language, what i meant is, the red div is supposed to be below the black one, then the green one is supposed to be below the black and red one, and the blue one below the green,red, and black divs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [z-index property not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937179/z-index-property-not-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the items an `position: relative`, that should work.

Edit: And don't use negative z-index. Just give the element which should lie on the top, the highest, the second one the second highest,...

So the code should looke like:

```
<style>
#head{
  position:relative;

    z-index:100;
    height:150;
    width:222;
    background-color:black;
    }

#item1{
    margin-top:-110;
    z-index:90;
    transition:0.5s;
    background-color:red;
    width:222;
    height:192;
  position: relative

}
#item1:hover{
    margin-top:0;
    transition:0.5s;
}
#item2{
    z-index:80;
    transition:0.5s;
    margin-top:-110;
    background-color:green;
    width:222;
    height:192;
  position: relative
}
#item2:hover{
    margin-top:0;
    transition:0.5s;
}
#item3{
    z-index:70;
    transition:0.5s;
    margin-top:-110;
    background-color:blue;
    width:222;
    height:192;
  position: relative
}
#item3:hover{
    margin-top:0;
    transition:0.5s;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it just now and now they would not hover down anymore.

Comment: I've updatet my answer. Try this code, that should work. :)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for this, and for your time! Now I'm going to study this code, Thank you so much, I can rest for a bit now. I can't upvote your answer, it says I need more reputation, How do I pick this as the answer? My apologies I am new here.

Comment: No problem. :) You can accept it on the left where the counter of the answers is. Just click on the grey tick.